# What is the max expiration time accepted by JWT tokens

Tags: jwt

I want to know what is the max value I can set of the JWT token expiration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

There is no rule about the expiration time. It mainly depends on the context where the token is used.

[RFC7519 section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4):

> The set of claims that a JWT must contain to be considered valid is context dependent and is outside the scope of this specification.

Thus you can consider that for critical processes, a short lifetime may be needed (only few seconds or minutes). For trivial contexts, one month lifetime, one year or even a token without expiration time could be acceptable.

Comment: How to specify token should not expire ?

Comment: Do not set any `exp` claim

Answer (score 0):

the maximum allowed age for tokens to still be valid. It is expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span zeit/ms. Eg: 1000, "2 days", "10h", "7d". A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default ("120" is equal to "120ms").There is no maximum limit.

Comment: *otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default* - **for JWT this is not true**. The `exp` of a token is a unix timestamp counting in seconds from 1970-1-1 00:00:00UTC. What you said might be true for the language/framework you're using, but this is a pure `JWT` question.