# IdentityServer 3: AccessTokenLifetime max value

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I use the IdentityServer3.
Is there more information about the setting "AccessTokenLifetime" and if there is a max. value?

I tried to set it to "int.MaxValue".

```
                     new Client
                     {
                          ClientName = "ClientName ",
                          ClientId = "ClientId",
                          Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,

                          ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                          {
                                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                          },

                          AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                          {
                                "openid",
                                "MyFramework"
                          },
                          AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                          AccessTokenLifetime = int.MaxValue,                     
                     },
```

[What is the max expiration time accepted by JWT tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594551/what-is-the-max-expiration-time-accepted-by-jwt-tokens)
This tells me there is no rule about the expiration time. But if I configure int.max it is not working.

The client gets the result "invalid_token" with no detailed explanation. And while starting the server, IdentityServer3 does not tell me that this setting is invalid.