# How to increase jwt expiration time PHP

Tags: php, jwt

I am using jwt token in php and i want to increase expiration time from 60 seconds to 60 days,How can i do this ?

Here is my code

```php
/* creating access token */
$issuedAt = time();
$expirationTime = $issuedAt + 60; // jwt valid for 60 seconds from the issued time
$payload = array('userid' => $phone, 'iat' => $issuedAt, 'exp' => $expirationTime);
$key = "xxxx";
$alg = 'xxxxx';
$tokens = JWT::encode($payload, $key, $alg);
```

Comment: Seems like you'd just need to multiply the 60 seconds (min) x 60 minutes (hr) x 24 (day) x 60 (total days) = 5184000.  However, it appears there's a max expiration time for tokens of 24 hrs : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594551/what-is-the-max-expiration-time-accepted-by-jwt-tokens

Comment: the first half of the above comment is true. But: @NathanChampion: there's no 24hrs limit and even in the linked q/a I don't read anything about it. Maybe there are certain implementations out there that enforce such a limit, but that's not the standard.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4), the expiration time (`exp` claim) should be the unix timestamp representation of the expiration time ("A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring leap seconds").

You're currently calculating it with `time() + 60`. That makes it 60 seconds after the time issued. You may simply change it according to your needs:

```php
/* creating access token */
$issuedAt = time();
// jwt valid for 60 days (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 60 days)
$expirationTime = $issuedAt + 60 * 60 * 24 * 60;
$payload = array(
  'userid' => $phone,
  'iat' => $issuedAt,
  'exp' => $expirationTime,
);
$key = "xxxx";
$alg = 'xxxxx';
$tokens = JWT::encode($payload, $key, $alg);
```